Stripped undercarriage bolt — What's on the other end?
2010 Silverado 1500; 500,000 km
I'm removing the running boards from my truck so that I can repair the rocker panels. Most of the bolts are breaking, so I'll just remove the running boards permanently and not reinstall them since they're not needed.
There is a bolt near the edge of the cab, midway along the cab. It appears to attach the cab to the frame, and is also being used for a bracket that attaches the running board to the truck.

On the passenger side of the truck, the ~5-inch bolt unthreaded without issue. There was blue Loctite on the threads of the bolt.
However, the driver's side of the truck didn't go as well. With a lot of effort and a 3-foot-long wrench extension, I got the bolt to move. But the bolt is just spinning freely; it's not unthreading.
My plan is to cut off the running board bracket with a grinder and leave the bolt (and bracket stub) in place since the bolt appears to be an important fastener; removing and replacing the bolt would be too difficult.

I think cutting the bracket will work. But out of curiosity, what's on the other end of the spinning bolt? Is there a welded nut, threaded steel plate, or something else? I'd just like to understand what I was up against. I couldn't see much on the passenger side in the bolt hole when I  removed the bolt since it was so long.
